# Check Two Dates in Sql

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a sql table named SHIFT, with columns:

```
No, Start, Duration(hours)
1,   7am,  7
2,   3pm,  7
3,  11pm,  7
```

How can I know which shift is running right now using a sql query?

Comment: is the start time in this exact format (3am, 7pm etc.), i.e is there 7:20pm for example or all records are like in your example?

Comment: what is the data type for `Start` ?

Comment: @mitkosoft, yeah it's in exact format like (7am, 3pm, 11pm). All records are like in my example

Comment: @Squirrel data type of Start in DateTime

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? If you have it available, the Time datatype seems more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one trick to do it

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Cast(Cast(start AS DATETIME) AS TIME) AS start_time,
                Cast(Getdate() AS TIME)               AS curr_time
         FROM   (VALUES (1,'7am',7),
                        (2,'3pm',7),
                        (3,'11pm',7)) tc (No, Start, Duration))
SELECT TOP 1 No,
             Start,
             Duration
FROM   cte
WHERE  Datediff(second, start_time, curr_time) >= 0
ORDER  BY Datediff(second, start_time, curr_time)
```

Converting `7am` to `datetime` gives you `1900-01-01 07:00:00.000`.

Now we can use the time part(`07:00:00.000`) in `1900-01-01 07:00:00.000` `datetime` to compare with the Current time

Comment: I may change timing in future to (8am, 4pm and 10pm) then i have to compile code again ?

Comment: @JaaZaib - That was sample data instead of `.. from (values..)` you can use your table directly

Comment: Got it now. 
I changed date time of my server to 12:30AM. Now This Query is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add computed column `finish` which would let you filter by `between` operator and `<` `>`

```
create table #test
(
  start time,
  lag   tinyint
)

insert into #test(start, lag)
values 
('7am', 7),
('8am', 3),
('10pm', 13),
('11am', 6)


alter table #test add finish as (dateadd(hh, lag, start))

/* all rows with computed column */
select * from #test

/* row with period current time falls in */
select *
from #test t
where cast(getdate() as time) between t.start and t.finish
order by t.start

drop table #test
```

Comment: @lvan Starostin, thanks for your response. I need to run this query every second. So do you think i will not effect the performance of my C# Application

Comment: This is a bit off topic but do you really need to run it every second, if the result only changes every few hours?

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson yeah really need to run it every second, Because i have some other functions related to this.

Comment: @JaaZaib, temp table is given to allow everyone (including me) to perform this sample code because I don't have your source table. My suggestion is to add computed column. This is performed once. Late may write simpler queries referring `start` and `finish` columns. Right now you don't have `finish` column. My suggestion is to add it. It has nothing to do with C# code.